# readUrl function gets parameters only for first call

Tags: javascript

i m calling a readURL() function  onchange a FILE INPUT field. with two parameters but on the second call it does not gettimg the value "1". it shows "0" only in second and third call..
Anyone?

```
  <input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="readURL(this,'0');"/>

  <input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="readURL(this,'1');"/>

  <input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="readURL(this,'2');"/>
```

Function Here:

```
function readURL(input,id) {
  alert(id)
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#'+id)
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

on alert(id) it alerts only 0

Comment: [Works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5L853xn/).

Comment: Ids should be unique for the document, you have 3 inputs with the same id